# Eager load with Doctrine2 entire hierarchy on one page

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I got a self-referencing entity designed to build a big hierarchy.

Now, 99% of the site will be more than fine using the lazy loading, and in fact I want the lazy loading as the default behavior.

However on an admin page, I want to dump the entire hierarchy in one shot. But when I do this with the lazy loading, it ends up being around 2000 queries by the time the page is done.

Is there some kind of join strategy that can drill down? Is there some kind of query-time setting that can tell Doctrine to just go ahead and automatically hydrate the children records?

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM AppBundle:Resource r WHERE r.managedBy IS NULL");
$query->setFetchMode("AppBundle:Resource", "manages", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
```

Here I'm getting the top level records, and drilling down.  But the `FETCH_EAGER` isn't really accomplishing anything.

Is there no way around this?

---

### Edit

Left Joining does this, but.. man............

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("
        SELECT r, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8
        FROM AppBundle:Resource r 
        LEFT JOIN r.manages m1 
        LEFT JOIN m1.manages m2
        LEFT JOIN m2.manages m3
        LEFT JOIN m3.manages m4
        LEFT JOIN m4.manages m5
        LEFT JOIN m5.manages m6
        LEFT JOIN m6.manages m7
        LEFT JOIN m7.manages m8
        WHERE r.managedBy  IS NULL");
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

But at least it gets it all in one query.

Any other way around this?

Comment: Can't you just join it in for eager loading? `SELECT r, m FROM AppBundle:Resource r LEFT JOIN r.manages m WHERE r.managedBy IS NULL`

Comment: as doctrine documentation says, you have three join strategies: `eager`, `lazy` and `extra lazy`. And there is no information to change fetch mode in recursive way at execution/query time (at least I didn't find it). The most correct way is to use query builder for specific queries (I am not sure about your task, but I guess, I used something similar in Symfony2 application using this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder)

Comment: @JimL wont that only just get the top level's children and basically leave the rest alone?  *EDIT* ya tried it out, only gets the second level lol there may be like 20 levels deep here :(

Comment: Updated question with my "discoveries" haha